# Share image contents from external url docker images in a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, cypress

Hey all StackOverflow People!
I have a question about docker-compose.

I have created the custom image in the registry, which I want to connect with another image from the public registry. In my case, this will be Cypress and one of my apps that run the build process.

In essence, I would like to share files to this Cypress, to then have the same tests running.

So it should run the `yarn start-server` first, then once done -> run the cypress tests.
I have looked around and couldn't find any article about this.

This is the piece of code I am trying to set up:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  e2e:
    build: .
    container_name: cypress
    image: cypress/included:6.2.0
    volumes:
      - static-content:/e2e
    depends_on:
      - front

  front:
    build: .
    command: ["yarn start-server"]
    container_name: front
    image: myinternalimage
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - static-content:/src
      - static-content:/cypress
      - static-content:/cypress.json
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: frontend


volumes:
  static-content:
    driver: local
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this to e2e container

```
working_dir: /e2e
volumes:
  - ./:/e2e
```

Check example [here](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-open-from-docker-compose/blob/master/e2e/docker-compose.yml)